# Django asyncio call in views doesn't work

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-asyncio, pypputeer

I'm struggling on this problem for quite a moment now.
I'm trying to export a view in pdf, using [pyppeteer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyppeteer). Here are my functions :

```
  async def export_pdf(url):                                                                             
      browser = await launch()                                                                           
      page = await browser.newPage() 
      await page.goto(url) 
      pdf = await page.pdf(                                                                              
          {   
              'printBackground': True                                                                    
          }   
      )       
      await browser.close()

      return pdf
```

And call it like that in my view:

```
   response.content = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
      export_pdf(self.request.get_full_path())
  )
```

But I got this error

> > RuntimeError at /export-pdf/1/2018/1/1/
> >     There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.

After some research I thought someone solved my problem and I called it like that (didn't quite understand, but it's something about django and my function not called in the main thread):

```
  loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
  asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
  response.content = loop.run_until_complete(
      export_pdf(
          asyncio.wait(
              export_pdf(self.request.get_full_path())
          )
      )
  )
  loop.close()
```

But now I have this error :

> > TypeError at /export-pdf/1/2018/1/1/
> >     expect a list of futures, not coroutine

I'm quite new to async in python, and the thing is, when i copy and paste the exact same code in my ipython shell, everything works fine.

Any explanation / light would be appreciated !

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**
After some research i've managed to come to another error, which is

> > signal only works in main thread

The weird thing is that the error come from `/usr/lib/python3.6/signal.py` which is not even from my virtualenv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your approach is the right one, except that there is an extra `asyncio.wait` call.
Simply do:

```
coroutine = export_pdf(self.request.get_full_path())

# nothing is done yet, we need to give this coroutine to an event loop which will run it
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
try:
   data = loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
finally:
    loop.close()

response.content = data
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried removing that asyncio.wait() already but i get the exact same error. It come from /usr/lib/python3.6/signal.py in signal which is weird cause it's not from my venv. I've updated my question

Comment: The signal error is pretty self-explainatory: your `export_pdf` function is trying to set a new signal handler, and this cannot be done from outside the main thread. More specifically, pyppeteer is trying to set three signal handlers: https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=signal&type=

Comment: This means that the pyppeteer library cannot really be used outside the main thread, and using the main thread is not an option in django. So, you can either have the main thread run this `export_pdf` call (very bad idea, you will lock your http stack while running export_pdf and if another request comes in it won't be handled correctly),

Comment: or you can use the three `handleSIGINT`, `handleSIGTERM`, `handleSIGHUB` option when launching pyppeteer, to make sure it doesn't try to add signal handlers (this *might* work but since pyppeteer is definitely not made to be used from threads, it might eventually break)

Comment: or, cleanest option by far: you can use *puppeteer* (the official nodeJS library), to create a new internal HTTP service which would expose a single `GET pdf?url=...` endpoint, this service would be running in nodeJS, and do the actual PDF rendering, and then you will be able to do a simple `requests.get('http://my-pdf-renderer/pdf?url=...')` in your django application

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers i'll try that and let you know.

Comment: It works when i used the three handle at false, but now i have some timeout, but only on some complex page. I'm going to accept this answer as the problem is now coming from something else, and as you explained well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do this as a celery task instead and use apply_async when calling the celery task. This might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjzyOyLbvN8

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the exact same thing than you.
But instead of messing up my Django server with threads, following Arthur advice, I decided to go with my own Puppeteer microservice.

But In the middle of the process, I found out someone had the same idea and created a ready to deploy tool for this exact purpose: https://github.com/alvarcarto/url-to-pdf-api

Basically, you just need to deploy this code (one click button if you're using Heroku), and then use the url of your app to start generating pdfs.